What is the proof that Term Finding in Calculus of Constructions ($\lambda{C}$) is undecidable?
It is mentioned in a textbook "Type Theory and Formal Proof: An Introduction", but couldn't find the paper or proof anywhere on the internet.
To quote the textbook:

The question of Term Finding, however, is decidable in $\lambda{\rightarrow}$ and $\lambda\underline{\omega}$, but
undecidable in all other systems.

It goes on to cite the "Church–Turing Undecidability Theorem" which I am already familiar with. However, I fail to see the connection. Merely, stating that since it is possible to encode Predicate Logic in $\lambda{C}$ does not warrant a justification to establish the undecidability of Term Finding in $\lambda{C}$.

The embedding of predicate logic into $\lambda C$ allows you to reduce the problem of deciding predicate logic to the problem of term finding. This is a classic technique: reducing an undecidable problem to another problem proves the second problem is also undecidable.

@MarkSaving But we know type checking is decidable in $\lambda{C}$, why isn't that also undecidable by that logic? Why Term Finding? Why not also well-typedness?

Because you can't encode the decidability problem for predicate logic as a type checking problem for $\lambda C$.

@NaïmFavier And where is the proof that encoding predicate logic is a term finding problem?

NVM I found the definition such that an inhabitant of a type is a proof of a proposition. Since the inhabitant I assume is always a term, it completes the proof. Thank you.

I don't know what you mean by that. The claim is that the problem of deciding the validity of a sentence of predicate logic reduces to the problem of finding a term $t$ such that $\vdash t : T$ in $\lambda C$. That is, you can encode a formula $\varphi$ as a type $T$ such that $\vdash t : T$ is derivable for some $t$ if and only if $\varphi$ is provable.

Type checking is equivalent to verifying a proof, which is usually computable, whereas term finding is equivalent to finding a proof, which usually isn't. I think this passage wasn't intended as a proof sketch, but rather as a plausibility argument. My understanding is the Church-Turing theorem is about the undecidability of classical predicate logic which isn't directly applicable here since the corresponding logic is not classical, though there may be a reasonably quick reduction via Godel/Gentzen translation or some such... I'm not sure of the details.
